# Como puedo mostrar ventanas de wpf en un menu tipo MDI

Tags: c#, wpf

Me encuentro desarrollando la interfaz de un sistema académico con WPF C# con estilos de `MAHAPPSMETRO` y `MATERIAL DESIGN` y necesito mostrar las ventanas del sistema en un menú estilo MDI de windows forms pero al ir investigando leí que WPF ya no se tomo encuenta el MDI.

Mi pregunta es se puede lograr una vista de MDI en WPF?
Y si no alguna sugerencia de como mostrar las ventanas del sistema sin que afecte la experiencia de usuario UX.

Comment: Como bien dices, en WPF microsoft desechó MDI(ya que tiene varias desventajas de manejo). Hay varias maneras de simularlo, como esta [en CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32362/Tabbed-MDI-in-WPF), pero yo te recomendaría que siguieras algun paradigma mas moderno que MDI.

Comment: Grasias por tu comentario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDI de forma nativa esta claro que no esta soportado, lo que se realiza en estos casos es mostrar las ventanas en un container, como se plantea en este ejemplo:

[Multiple Document Interface (MDI) in WPF](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Multiple-Document-059b96a8)

Esto tambien puede aplicarse como `Docking Windows` con componentes como ser

[AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/)

creo que estas alternativas son mejores que las ventanas MDI

Comment: Grasias por la respuesta me fue de gran ayuda ya por donde empesar a investigar